# Path algebra on quivers of type ADE

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver, dynkin-diagrams

Let $K$ be a field. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ consider the equioriented $A_n$-quiver. It is easy to see that the path algebra $K[A_n]$ is isomorphic as a $K$-algebra to the algebra of upper triangular $n\times n$-matrices with entries in $K$. Do the path algebras of the $D_n$-quivers and $E_n$-quivers (oriented in some way) have a similiarly easy description?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘equioriented’ in types D and E? They each have a unique vertex of valency 3, so one could take that as the unique sink, but then we have three sources.

Comment: That was nonsense — you are right. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the quiver is a tree, then there is at most one path between any two vertices, and so we can always regard the path algebra as a subalgebra of a matrix algebra, with rows/columns indexed by the vertices, and such that the unique path from $i$ to $j$, if it exists, is sent to the elementary matrix $E_{ji}$.